# list truncation: set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_options, [max_depth(100)]) having no effect

Tags: list, prolog, truncation, prolog-toplevel

All the questions regarding how to disable list truncation had the answer to use some variantion of this:

```
?- set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_options, [quoted(true), portray(true), max_depth(100), priority(699)]).
```

For me this does not work, see here:

```
?- length(L, 25).
L = [_7572, _7578, _7584, _7590, _7596, _7602, _7608, _7614, _7620|...].

?- set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_options, [quoted(true), portray(true), max_depth(1000), priority(699)]).
true.

?- length(L, 25).
L = [_7596, _7602, _7608, _7614, _7620, _7626, _7632, _7638, _7644|...].
```

According to for instance this anwer, this should work:[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525995/how-to-expand-a-resulting-list-in-swi-prolog)

Has to have to do with the version of my Prolog. I am using `SWI-Prolog version 7.4.2 for x86_64-darwin16.5.0`. Does anyone know why this does not work with my version and how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this command instead:

```
set_prolog_flag(answer_write_options, [quoted(true), portray(true), max_depth(100), priority(699)]).
```

where replaced  `toplevel_print_options` with  `answer_write_options`.